# To Create a Stackable Table Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

So I'm trying to create a super simple plugin that stacks a table when the view port is scrolled down to a mobile view port. Instead of using CSS pseudo selectors (not allowed in jQuery) I'm absolute positioning a span. The CSS works it's just the span in being multiplied because everything's within an .each() statement.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.stackableTable = function() {

        console.log(this);

        var $table = this;

        $table.each(function(h, table) {
            $th = $(this).find("thead th");
            $tr = $(this).find("tbody tr");
            $td = $tr.find("td");

            //console.log($th, $td, $tr);
            $tr.each(function(i, tr){
                $th.each(function(j, th){
                    var headCopy = $(this).text();
                    $td.each(function(k, td){
                        var columHead = $('<span />').attr("class", "header").html(headCopy);
                        $td.eq(k).prepend(columHead);
                    }); 
                });
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Any help with the correct nesting is greatly appreciated, using either jQuery or JavaScript. See CodePen here: http://codepen.io/michaeladamek/pen/jPQgZg

Thanks!